# Nil while unwrapping an Optional IBOutlet value

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, iboutlet

I have got a `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` for an `IBOutlet`.

In my custom view, I have associated my outlet with a `XIB` file. I have double checked this. This is how it looks like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel! {
    didSet {
        label.textColor = .redColor()
    }
}
```

My implementation of `layoutSubviews` looks like:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.frame.size.width
}
```

Despite the fact, that `layoutSubviews` method has to be called after UI elements initialisation, I get an error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

This error is triggered by line:

```
label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.frame.size.width
```

Why is that so? How to fix it?

Comment: Maybe the link between storyboard and your file is broken, try to create a new link (ctrl + drag) to your IBoutlet

Comment: I have tried this multiple times. The link is OK.

Comment: How are you creating the view controller instance?

Comment: This is a view, not a view controller

Comment: maybe `@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel? = nil { didSet { label?.textColor = .redColor() } }`, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead of `layoutSubviews`. You UI elements should be ready in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, but not necessary in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: Yea, but the problem is, that this is a view, not a view controller

Comment: `awakeFromNib()` ?

Comment: This method doesn't fit well for me.

Comment: may i ask why? But than, in the viewController, in what you present your uiview, set the label preferedwidth in that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` call.

Comment: I am implementing hack to enable dynamic table view cells for iOS 7. I need to set this property after layout changes.

Comment: Dude, why are you still developing for iOS 7? Probably it is not your decision, but have you checked the latest usage stats for iOS 7??

Comment: Trust me, pal, if it is up to me, I wold have been dropped iOS 7 support long time ago :).

Comment: yeah i guess so! So trying to call the viewController's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` function? Just reference the UIView in your viewController, and do it from there?

Comment: In this case I would have to expose my 'UIView' properties. I would like to keep them private. Also, this doesn't sounds right. But I agree, it should work.

Comment: you have to expose the `UIView`, but you could keep the properties private, and set the width with a public function.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the crash from happening by safely unwrapping label with an if let statement.

```
if let mylabel = label {
   mylabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = mylabel.frame.size.width
}
```

Comment: Yes, but for me it is interesting, why label is not ready? Also, where is the guarantee, that `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` will be setup?

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588066/loading-custom-uiview-from-nib-all-subviews-contained-in-nib-are-nil

Answer (score 1):

You should use:

```
label?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = label.frame.size.width
```

This before in an early call of layoutSubviews the outlet could not be yet setted, but in the next call will be. Using otional chaining you can avoid explicit optional unwrapping. if label is nil the assignment is skipped automatically.